# Regex to get match up through second to last occurrence of a string

Tags: regex

If I have the following string:

`hello/everyone/good/bye/world`

I want to match everything up through the second to last forward slash:

`hello/everyone/good/`

But the number of slashes may vary.

What would the regex be to do this? Been googling around to no avail.

Comment: Why can't you just explode (or whatever your language has equivalent) the text by the `/` and just do a for loop except for the last two?

Comment: I'm creating a sublime text snippet that has to be xml based and only supports text substitutions via regex — http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regular expression, use `split` and take advantage of "slicing".

```
t = "hello/everyone/good/bye/world"
ts = t.split("/")
print "/".join( ts[0:-2] ) + "/"
```

This prints

```
hello/everyone/good/
```

This answer is for python2 (you did not specify which language), there are equivalent commands in some other languages.   For example, java has a `String.split()` method (to complicate things, it requires a regular expression). Consult the documentation for the language you are using.

Comment: I'm creating a sublime text snippet that has to be xml based and only supports text substitutions via regex — http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know "sublime text".  However, I had a quick look at their documentation, and saw https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin--net-22685 Maybe that can help (you would have access to python language).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this https://regex101.com/r/bH2vI0/1:

```
((\w+\/)+(?!\w+\/\w+))
```

Not sure if sublime allows lookaheads though, but basically just match every `word + /` except for last two. `[A-z]` might be better if you don't want digits and `_`

Comment: This appears to match the second to last word as well though, no?

Comment: Depending on your grouping, but the first major group should match what you want. I don't know anything about sublime's regex stuff.